# How can a Silverlight app talk to another app on a Mac?

Tags: .net, objective-c, mac, silverlight, porting

Is there any way that a Silverlight out-of-browser app can communicate with another app (for example an Objective-C app) installed on a Mac?

Any help or suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Comment: That would be a security nightmare of the first magnitude.  A Mac OS Desktop App, however, can talk to a web site that's hosting this silverlight app.  What are you hoping to accomplish?  What do you want to do?  Why does this seem like a good idea?

Comment: I'm looking for a solution/workaround for the missing p/invoke feature of Silverlight on the Mac.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617727/can-silverlight-can-run-a-library-written-in-c-on-pc-mac-linux.  Asked and answered.

Comment: @S.Lott Thanks for the link but in my view it is not exactly the same question (see my comment below) and it is not yet answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you mean by "a Silverlight out-of-browser app" and "another app (for example an Objective-C app) installed on a Mac" are simply two processes, and you're looking for an interprocess communication mechanism, there are several possibilities.

Since Silverlight has both a networking (sockets) API and a filesystem API, those should both be good options. I'd probably use TCP/IP networking, which I'd expect to be pretty fast when both processes are on the same machine.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and yes: Some kind of an interprocess communication mechanism is what I mean. As I understand, Silverlight on a Mac can only connect to sockets but not open it. So the solution would be to write an Objective-C app which opens a socket and the SL app could then connect to it. Would this be possible?

Comment: I can't speak in detail to the SL side, but an ObjC app can certainly use the C-based sockets API to do anything possible with a TCP/IP connection, and can probably use the Cocoa NSStream class to do it too.

Comment: ok, thanks, so the solution in my case would be: build an ObjC app which opens a socket, starts the SL app and then runs hidden in the background. The SL app can then connect to the ObjC using sockets :-)